# Harmonic Series and Its Divergence by Abel Sum and Cesaro Sum

Tags: real-analysis, divergent-series, cesaro-summable

Already I know that harmonic series, $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k $$ is divergent series.

And, it is also divergent by Abel Sum or Cesaro Sum.

However, I do not know how to prove it is divergent by concept of Abel or Cesaro.

Abel Sum or Cesaro Sum do not exist in this problem.

But, how can I prove it?

I have tried to prove for long time...

Can you please show your work?

Answer (score 1):

A simple trick is to consider that:
$$\frac{1}{n}\geq\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\tag{1}$$
holds regardless of which concept of convergence you are using, and the partial sums of the RHS of $(1)$ are fairly easy to compute by the telescopic property:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\log\prod_{n=1}^{N}\frac{n+1}{n} = \log(N+1).\tag{2}$$
As an alternative, given that $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$, we have:
$$ \frac{H_1+\ldots+H_n}{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{j}\frac{1}{k}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{n+1-j}{j}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)H_n-1.\tag{3}$$

Comment: I see your idea. lim [x^Nlog(N+1)] does not exist, right? 

And, eqaution (3) is for Cesaro. But, If we get the fact that Abel sum is not possible, we naturally would know Cesaro Sum is also not possible. Right?

Comment: @qyong: yes, right.

Answer (score 0):

Since the term of the Harmonic series are of O(1/n). Suppose, if the Harmonic series is Cesaro summable, then by Hardy's theorem, the series is convergent, but Harmonic series is divergent. So, Harmonic series is not Cesaro summable.

Answer (score 0):

Because $H(n)>\ln(n+1)$, we want to show that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln((n+1)!)}{n}$$diverges, which was derived by applying the addition to product rule. Because $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x!}{e^x}=\infty$, this limit diverges.